# teradata sql query to assign same rownumbers

Tags: teradata

How to assign same rownumber to group of sequence records. Refer the below example orderno.s 550 &650 are having two sets of running sequence numbers
I wanted to assign same row number for each corresponding ordernumber and set of sequence numbers(1,2,3)

```
Order,   Item,  SequenceNumber
550,     AA,      1
550,     AA,      2
550,     AA,      3

550,     AA,      1
550,     AA,      2
550,     AA,      3
550,     AA,      4

650,     AA,      1
650,     AA,      2
650,     AA,      3

650,     AA,      1
650,     AA,      2
650,     AA,      3
650,     AA,      4
```

Expected result should be with the new rownumber column populated as below.

```
Order,    Item,  SequenceNumber ,    Rownumber
550,      AA,      1,                     1
550,      AA,      2,                     1
550,      AA,      3,                     1

550,      AA,      1,                     2
550,      AA,      2,                     2
550,      AA,      3,                     2
550,      AA,      4,                     2

650,      AA,      1,                     1
650,      AA,      2,                     1
650,      AA,      3,                     1

650,      AA,      1,                     2
650,      AA,      2,                     2
650,      AA,      3,                     2
650,      AA,      4,                     2
```

Comment: thanks dnoeth, your solution worked for me...

Answer (score 2):

You need nested OLAP functions, but of course there must be some column to order your data:

```
SELECT ...
   Sum(flag) -- create the group number
   Over (PARTITION BY Order, Item
                   ORDER BY whatever
                   ROWS Unbounded Preceding)
FROM
 (
   SELECT ...
      -- find the row where a new group starts
      CASE WHEN Min(SequenceNumber) 
                Over (PARTITION BY Order, Item
                      ORDER BY whatever
                      ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) + 1 = SequenceNumber
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1
      END AS flag
   FROM tab
 ) AS dt
```

Answer (score 0):

From your existing table, you need to create an ALTER statement so that you can add new column.

`ALTER TABLE mytableName ADD Rownumber INT;`

After the statement has been successfully executed, you can now update all the records,

`UPDATE  myTableName
SET     Rownumber = (some logic statement depending on table values)`

edit:
I'd be happy to help with that (some logic statement...), but I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for from your question.

Comment: I'm not concerned about adding the column, I'm looking for logic to populate the rownumber column (I mean assigning same rownumber to each set of running sequence and orderno.

Comment: Can you please explain what the below code does...                   
                                                                                                      
  Sum(flag) -- create the group number
   Over (PARTITION BY Order, Item
                   ORDER BY whatever
                   ROWS Unbounded Preceding)

Comment: I'm not really sure how Sum(flag) creates new group number..in above case..

Comment: Might want to add those comments to the other question so he gets notified. From that first comment I understand what you're looking to do now, but he has the right answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT
  OrderNumber
, ItemCode
, SequenceNumber
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderNumber, SequenceNumber, SequenceNumberCount) AS RowNumber
FROM
(
    SELECT
      OrderNumber
    , ItemCode
    , SequenceNumber
    , COUNT(SequenceNumber) OVER(PARTITION BY OrderNumber, SequenceNumber ORDER BY OrderNumber, ItemCode) AS SequenceNumberCount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 550 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 1 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
        SELECT 550 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 2 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
        SELECT 550 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 3 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
        SELECT 550 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 1 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
        SELECT 550 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 2 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
        SELECT 550 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 3 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
        SELECT 550 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 4 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
        SELECT 650 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 1 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
        SELECT 650 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 2 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
        SELECT 650 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 3 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
        SELECT 650 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 1 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
        SELECT 650 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 2 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
        SELECT 650 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 3 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
        SELECT 650 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 4 AS SequenceNumber 
    ) AS data
) AS interim_calculation
ORDER BY
  OrderNumber
, RowNumber
, SequenceNumber;
```

Update:

> Updated SQL to remove redundant complexity based on [@dnoeth's
>   comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43943180/teradata-sql-query-to-assign-same-rownumbers#comment74936913_43948485):
>
> ```
> SELECT
>   OrderNumber
> , ItemCode
> , SequenceNumber
> , Row_Number() Over(PARTITION BY OrderNumber, SequenceNumber ORDER BY SequenceNumber) AS RowNumber
> FROM
> (
>     SELECT 550 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 1 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
>     SELECT 550 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 2 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
>     SELECT 550 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 3 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
>     SELECT 550 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 1 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
>     SELECT 550 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 2 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
>     SELECT 550 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 3 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
>     SELECT 550 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 4 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
>     SELECT 650 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 1 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
>     SELECT 650 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 2 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
>     SELECT 650 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 3 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
>     SELECT 650 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 1 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
>     SELECT 650 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 2 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
>     SELECT 650 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 3 AS SequenceNumber UNION ALL
>     SELECT 650 AS OrderNumber, 'AA' As ItemCode, 4 AS SequenceNumber 
> ) AS data
> ORDER BY
>   OrderNumber
> , RowNumber
> , SequenceNumber;
> ```

which results in:

[image: results]

Comment: That's way too complicated: `Row_Number() Over(PARTITION BY OrderNumber, SequenceNumber ORDER BY SequenceNumber) AS RowNumber` returns the same without nesting :-)